# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable when tensorflow operations added on keras output

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a pre-trained Keras Sequential model called agent, and I'm trying to fine-tune it with a loss function.

```
json_file = open('model/prior_model_RMSprop.json', 'r')
json_model = json_file.read()
json_file.close()

agent = model_from_json(json_model)
prior = model_from_json(json_model)
# load weights into model
agent.load_weights('model/model_RMSprop.h5')
prior.load_weights('model/model_RMSprop.h5')

agent_output = agent.output
prior_output = prior.output

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(agent_output - prior_output))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

So far, everything works fine. However, when I add some basic tensorflow operations, the error happens

```
agent_logits = tf.cast(tf.argmax(agent_output, axis = 2), dtype = tf.float32)
prior_logits = tf.cast(tf.argmax(prior_output, axis = 2), dtype = tf.float32)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(agent_logits - prior_logits))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

So the tensorflow operations break the connection between the model and the loss function? I've been stucked here for almost 2 weeks so pls help. I'm also not very clear about how to update a Keras model's trainable weights with the loss function I defined. Any hints or related links will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Where is the input data?

Comment: The input data is generated from a function called "sample(BATCH_SIZE)".  With a fixed start token, the pre-trained model 'agent' will generated BATCH_SIZE number of fixed length of sequences.

Comment: prior and agent are exactly the same, the result will be constantly 0

Comment: Thank you! I actually has another reinforcement metric. For each generated sequence A (come from agent.predict() ), there is a metric function S(A) and returns a float. Then the loss function is tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(p_a_agent - p_a_prior - tf.multiply(2.0, score))). I keep getting None gradients. Is it because that I used the predict() function which can't be traced back to the graph?